# Overloading << operator: struct with vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, overloading, ostream

- Overloading << for vectors works.
- Overloading << for custom structs works.
- The combination works as well.

But if I use the << operator on a **struct with a vector of structs**, compilation fails.
I made up a little example to showcase the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    out << "[";
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        out << *it;
        if (std::next(it) != v.end()) {
            out << ", ";
        }
    }
    out << "]";
    return out;
}

namespace xyz {

struct Item {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Aggregation {
    std::vector<Item> items; 
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Item& item) {
    out << "Item(" << "a = " << item.a << ", " << "b = " << item.b << ")";
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Aggregation& agg) {
    out << "Aggregation(" << "items = " << agg.items << ")";
    return out;
}

}  // namespace xyz

int main() {
    xyz::Aggregation agg;
    agg.items.emplace_back(xyz::Item{1, 2});
    agg.items.emplace_back(xyz::Item{3, 4});

    std::cout << agg.items << std::endl;  // works: [Item(a = 1, b = 2), Item(a = 3, b = 4)]
    std::cout << agg << std::endl;        // fails, expected: Aggregation(items = [Item(a = 1, b = 2), Item(a = 3, b = 4))
}
```

Link to compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/a8dccf

```
<source>: In function 'std::ostream& xyz::operator<<(std::ostream&, const xyz::Aggregation&)':
<source>:35:41: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const std::vector<xyz::Item>')
   35 |     out << "Aggregation(" << "items = " << agg.items << ")";
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~
      |                           |                    |
      |                           |                    const std::vector<xyz::Item>
      |                           std::basic_ostream<char>
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `main` function, when you write this line:

```
std::cout << agg.items << std::endl;
```

the compiler will look in the global namespace for all overloads of `operator<<`. The correct overload is chosen via overload resolution, and so the call works.

When you write the similar code here

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Aggregation& agg) {
    out << "Aggregation(" << "items = " << agg.items << ")";
    return out;
}
```

since this code is in namespace `xyz`, the compiler will first look up the overloads of `operator<<` in namespace `xyz`. Once it finds any overloads at all, it will stop looking for additional overloads. However, since the actual `operator<<` that you want is not in namespace `xyz`, overload resolution fails, and you get an error.

The fix for this is to simply move the `operator<<` taking a `vector<T>` into namespace `xyz`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cr5Wxr).

---

If you actually want an `operator<<` that takes a `vector` of any type to be accessible from the global scope as well as namespace `xyz`, then you can define it in the global scope as you have done in your question. Then just bring the operator into `xyz`, or preferably, into the specific functions in namespace `xyz` where you need them, like this:

```
namespace xyz 
{
  // using ::operator<<;  // if you want all of `xyz` to see the global overload
 
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Aggregation& agg) 
  {
    using ::operator<<;  // if you only want the global overload to be visible in this function
    out << "Aggregation(" << "items = " << agg.items << ")";
    return out;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/En99d4) that shows how to stream a `vector<int>` as well as a `vector<xyz::Item>`.

---

Thanks to @NathanPierson for pointing out that the `using` declaration can be local to the functions where it's needed, instead of polluting the entirety of namespace `xyz`.

Comment: But then if somebody wants to use `operator<<` for, say, a `std::vector<int>`, it won't trigger ADL and won't search the `xyz` namespace. Is there a way to avoid the code duplication so that the function works for vectors generally, but is still found in the case of namespace `xyz` classes?

Comment: Great, thanks! I'd like to keep the overloading for vectors in one place for the whole project. Is there any way to make is accessible in other namespaces without rewriting the function again and again?

Comment: @luxderfux To clarify, you want `vector`s of any type to be streamable, or only vectors of specific types?

Comment: @cigien: `vector`s of any type

Comment: Excellent. Pleasantly surprised how painless the syntax on that using declaration is.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yeah, but note that this will bring in *every* overload of `operator<<`. I've decided not to increase the length of the answer substantially by voicing my opinion on whether doing this is actually a good idea ;)

Comment: One thing I will note along those lines is that you don't have to bring it in to the entirety of the `xyz` namespace, you can also have `using ::operator<<;` in just the specific function for streaming `Aggregate`s.

Comment: @NathanPierson That is *way* better, don't know how I missed that :( Thanks a ton, added to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran over a similar issue again with the fmt library (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2093). Another working solution seems to be adding `operator<<` overloading for std containers directly to namespace std:

```cpp
namespace std {

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    out << "[";
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        out << *it;
        if (std::next(it) != v.end()) {
            out << ", ";
        }
    }
    out << "]";
    return out;
}

}  // namespace std
```

Link to compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/o7c9WP

I feel bad about adding something to namespace std though. Any thoughts on this?